# Check if app is connected to the internet

Tags: java, android

How do I check if my app is connected to the internet?

I found this post, but it seems you can only check if connection is available. [Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

That post did have the correct answer, I was just too far from my wifi and would always fail the test. The problem is solved.

I would like to be able to check something like this:

```
if(!isConnectedToInternet())
{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please connect to the internet.", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: `isConnectedToInternet` is what? a method or simple variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer from the link you attached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239019/3152527) actually do almost the same with what you are trying to achieve. You just need to modify few line:

```
private boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork= connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return  activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

You may check the [documentation & guides](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) from Android

Comment: I was thinking that code was not working, but in fact I was too far from my wifi. So original answer was correct and so are you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try checking like this:

```
private boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

checking here:

```
if(!isConnectedToInternet())
{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please connect to the internet.", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code that is work fine for me

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Check like this

```
boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    if (isInternetPresent) {


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: do you care to explain ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that there is an established connection

```
private boolean isConnected() {
ConnectivityManager cm 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected() && cm.requestRouteToHost(activeNetworkInfo.getType(), yourHostAddress);
}
```

and then check if there is a route to the host you want (you can use Google for testing purposes). Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestRouteToHost(int, int)

Hope it helps.